# Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<JSON>'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  getStepList(): Observable<JSON>  {                  
            this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');                
            let options = new RequestOptions({
                method: RequestMethod.Post,
                url: "FeedbackMaster.aspx/getStepList",                   
                headers: this.headers,
                  body:{log:this.login}
            });
            return this._http.request(new Request(options)).retry(2)
            .map((response: Response)=>this.extractData(response))
            .do(data => {this.temp=data, console.log('getStepList:'+ JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.temp.d)))})
            .catch(this.handleError);                  
    }

    extractData(res: Response) {
           let body = res.json();
           return body || { }; //<--- not wrapped with data
     }
          handleError(error: any) {
         console.error('An error occurred', error);
          return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
   }
```

.......................................................................................................

Error

```
[ts]
 Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<JSON>'.
 Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'JSON'.
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: If it is compile time error then check your 'extractData' function's return type. It must return JSON object. 
And if it is run time error then check if your 'extractData' is returning something or not.

Comment: its complie time error

Comment: Please add the code of your `handleError` function

Comment: @ yurzui  pls check code

Comment: Try to change `Promise.reject` to `Observable.throw`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`.map()`needs to return something, for example:

```
.map((response: Response) => { this.extractData(response); return response.json(); })
```

The `return response.json()` yields `Observable<JSON>`. Without returning anything from `.map()` it becomes `Observable<void>`.